# Browser Caching of images and videos served via php query strings

Tags: php, apache, caching, browser-cache

I'm making a website that requires users to be logged in to access anything, thus all video and image assets are served via requests to a php file, like:

`example.com/media/?clip=668&q=h`
the server checks to see the user is allowed, and if so, responds with a mp4 file, "q=h" meaning "i want the half-res video"

and
`example.com/media/?clip=668&q=t`
responds with a jpeg file, "q=t" meaning "i want the thumbnail"

it all works well enough on my site, i've got the mime types and everything set. however, Chrome never caches any of these assets, so my bandwidth is skyrocketing. in the Network tab of Chrome Inspector, my css and js files come "(from memory cache)" or "(from browser cache)", but all my heavy assets, the images and videos, don't cache.

how can i get the browser to cache these?

[image]

Comment: make suer the script serving the files sends the headers  Cache-Control,eTag,max-age not sure which other ones are going to be required here, but this is probably were the issue is

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks @tim!

The problem was in the headers i was serving alongside my media. I looked at the response in Chrome and it said:

`Cache-Control: must-revalidate, no-cache, no-store`

I didn't set these, it must be a default of apache since I'm serving through a script? Anyways, to fix, I just added:

`Cache-Control: public`

to my PHP file and it seems to be working!