# Application that Streams Videos from Local Cache - in Browser?

Tags: caching, video-streaming, browser-cache, vlc, chromecast

I've built a webapp to host low-res proxies of our teams video files. The webapp is primarily for tagging and searching video. Additionally, I'd like to be able to play a random playlist of clips on TVs around the office. I've implemented this by "Casting Tab" to a Chromecast, and it works fine.

However, now I'm running up against the bandwidth limitations of my host. Latency and everything is fine, but to run a single TV's 2.5Mbps stream 8hrs a day for 23 days a month comes to about 207 GB/month, 20% of my alotted 1TB monthly transfer.

How can i build something that will "cache" these clips client-side, so that it doesnt re-download them unnecessarily? There are about 1000 clips. I'd prefer to keep it connected to my webapp via browser or some API endpoint so the `RAND()` stream of clips is constantly updated as people add to it.

Note: I asked a related question yesterday, and it seemed to fix my specific issue, but it doesn't seem to have worked at scale, so I'm broadening the approach a bit. [Browser Caching of images and videos served via php query strings](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54468818/browser-caching-of-images-and-videos-served-via-php-query-strings)

Answer (score 0):

Shaka Player has built-in support for [offline playback](https://shaka-player-demo.appspot.com/docs/api/tutorial-offline.html), along with a pretty good API for listing offline assets, and removing them again.

This would require that you have your videos in MPEG-DASH format. Luckily Google also has a tool available for that. [Shaka Packager](https://github.com/google/shaka-packager) can take your mp4's and package them for MPEG-DASH, provided the MP4's follow some simple requirements.

You could probably build something yourself using similar mechanisms to the Shaka Player, but it seems much easier to use Shaka for doing it.

Comment: i've done a fair amount of googling, to little avail. how is DASH better/worse than h.264?

Comment: @Ben You would still use H.264. DASH is just a different way to package it, than simple MP4 files. H.264 and AAC are video and audio codecs, they can be packaged in different ways, MP4 files, mkv files etc. MPEG-DASH is a way to split streaming into smaller segments, which makes for better delivery over the internet. Similar to what HLS does on Apple devices. So compared to using your MP4 file, there will be no change in quality, because the codec is the same. It will just be split in to a number of smaller segments instead of one large one.